# uuencode hangs?

Tags: debian, email

I need to send myself a database backup from a remote docker container running Ubuntu. I ssh into the container and run:

```
uuencode dbexport.pgsql | mail -s "DB" phk@2klic.com
```

It seems to hang forever so I run only the first part:

```
uuencode dbexport.pgsql
```

Which also seems to hang forever. Any suggestions to debug this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command to `uuencode` a file should be:

```
uuencode dbexport.pgsql dbexport.pgsql
```

where the 1st name is the actual filename, and the 2nd the destination name for a possible restore in a different file.

So the correct way seems more like:

```
uuencode dbexport.pgsql dbexport.pgsql | mail -s "DB" phk@2klic.com
```

I actually prefer to install `mpack`

```
sudo apt-get install mpack
```

and to send an email in MIME format, would do:

```
mpack -s "DB" dbexport.pgsql phk@2klic.com
```